# ionic serve of IONIC 1 project, not working in ionic 4 cli

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Today after launching of IONIC 4 Beta, I updated my IONIC CLI to 4.0.1. After as i was trying to serve one of my IONIC v1 project using

> ionic serve command it was showing below error and warnings to me

```
ionic serve
```

> ionic-v1 serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --lr-port 35729 --dev-port 53703
>   [v1] 'ionic-v1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [v1] operable program or batch file.

[INFO] Looks like @ionic/v1-toolkit isn't installed in this project.

```
   This package is required for ionic serve. For more details, please see the CHANGELOG:
   https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/packages/ionic/CHANGELOG.md#4.0.0
```

[ERROR] A utility CLI has unexpectedly closed.

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: Downgrade your CLI version when you want to use IONIC 1 and when you will use ionic 3 or 4 then you can upgrade it easily. Better and faster way for this case.

Here is all versions list https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic

USE: npm install ionic@YOUR_VERSION_NUMBER

Comment: I have the same kind of issue, can't run an old ionic v1 project from the last ionic version 6.12.3. How to downgrade and to which version please?

Answer (score 16):

As suggested in warning
*[INFO] Looks like @ionic/v1-toolkit isn't installed in this project.*

> I tried to install @ionic/V1-toolkit using below command and i was able to use ionic serve for my IONIC V1 project from IONIC V4.0.1 CLI.

```
npm install @ionic/v1-toolkit -g
```

Comment: after installing @ionic/v1-toolkit i am getting Assertion **`args[1]->IsString()'** error, for that i had run **npm i natives**, after that i am able to run ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

Install ionic lab

```
npm install @ionic/lab
```

This will resolve the issue

[Ionic lab doesn’t work with ionic CLI 4.0.0](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-lab-doesnt-work-with-ionic-cli-4-0-0/136283/2)